# How to avoid AggregateException that contains a TypeInitializationException when creating a table with sqlite

Tags: xamarin, sqlite-net-pcl

In my DB ctor:

```
databasePath = GetPath(docsFolder);
connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(databasePath);
connection.CreateTableAsync<BO>().Wait();
```

Database path is 
/data/user/0/com.companyname.AppName/files/fn.db3
(Package name filtered only here)

But that occurs when creating a table:
Unhandled Exception:
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.

In BO I removed already DateTime:
Currently only string and int are types that are applied.

```
public class BO
{
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int ID { get; set; }

        public string From { get; set; }

        public string To { get; set; }

        public string Note { get; set; }
}
```

NuGet:

```
  <package id="sqlite-net-pcl" version="1.4.118" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green" version="1.1.5" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
  <package id="SQLitePCLRaw.core" version="1.1.5" targetFramework="portable45-net45+win8+wpa81" />
```

EDIT:
In the `AggregateException` is one `TypeInitializationException`, which occurs when creating the table. But `SQLite.SQLiteConnection` is stated as TypeName concerning the `TypeInitializationException` when debugging.
`SQLiteAsyncConnection connection` was clearly defined in the code. 
Is there a privilege missing to create a db file?

Comment: AggregateException is not informative. Try to catch it and print its e.Flatten().InnerExceptions. Or just stop in the debugger and check the inner exceptions. You should get there the actual error.

Comment: Post edited. A TypeInitializationException occurs.

Comment: Can you please post the whole exception message?

Comment: When reviewing the AggregateException entry, the debugger refers within the one entry only to the name(TypeInitializationException ) and the type(SQLite.SQLiteConnection). No message is displayed in the debugger. I will check whether printing is possible.

Comment: Ta-da. The type initializer for 'SQLite.SQLiteConnection' threw an exception. That's really helpful. Isn't it.

Comment: Yes it is. Now tr

Comment: Now try to look at

Comment: Or use Flatten() to see them all.

Comment: As already mentioned, only one exception entry. InnerException does not provide additional information.

Comment: Maybe you can use "break when thrown" feature in VS studio exception helper and break when the first, most inner exception is thrown. And then check its message. There is really no other way to see what's going on.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Perhaps I overlooked something. In the meantime, I played with additional references and it is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 packages were missing within the Android project.

```
SQLitePCLRaw.lib.e_sqlite3.android
SQLitePCLRaw.provider.e_sqlite3.android
```